# Impermanent Graph Database - Neo4j In Memory with PHP

Tags: java, php, unit-testing, neo4j, neo4jphp

Looking at [unit-testing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html) in the docs, I would like to be able to do that in PHP as well. There's [this library](http://github.com/vinelab/NeoEloquent) we're using and we have a lot of testing with the database to do.

Using Neo4j 2.1.3, any idea on how to have that done with a programming language other than Java?

Comment: You install an start a server as part of your test setup, then you clean out the data, setup your test-dataset and run your test-queries. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Neo4j RestTest](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-resttest), which you can use from any programming language via REST API.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors.

Comment: It means that I can use all rest endpoints? -> https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/ We are triing to mock neo4j for a php project with codeception.

Answer (score -1):

This question may have an answer for you:
[Unit Testing a Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547302/unit-testing-a-website)

There are a number of free systems to do this for PHP. They may have some learning curve though. Some of these include:

1. TOAST (http://jensroland.com/projects/toast/)
2. Fitnesse (http://fitnesse.org/)
3. Canoo WebTest
4. And so on

However, if you are into the do-it-yourself mood and you are using a platform like Codeigniter, you have ways of profiling your app using the benchmarking class and presenting the performance using Google Charts. This may require having the dev skills to implement and some type of storage for the tracking data - such as a MySQL database or flat file.

Comment: Hey @AlZziwa, wrong question answered, any idea about transient Neo4J databases and PHP?

Comment: @JohnMark13 you are right to down vote me. I did not read that the question was focused on only Neo4J. My response would be suitable for PHP unit testing in general.